# How to develop Echo State Network (ESN) from scarch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
class ESN(property of esn):
   def get_weight(shape of weight):
```

I want to develop a python class of ESN(), and it has a function get_weight, In the training time of an NN, I want to fix some of the weight and these come from ESN by calling function get_weight().
For example
w_esn = get_weight((3,2))

```
f = (w*x + w_esn* g+ c)
```

for the g data, It won't be updated, It only updates w for x.
Now how can I develop the ESN for getting the weight that I need, is there any module or library that gives me only the weight based on the property of ESN.